# Power BI costum column Column, List.Sum "column of the table was not found", why?

Tags: indexing, sum, powerquery, cumulative-sum

I am trying to do a running total in PBI, in Power Query.

I have a Sum column, which I created by summing three columns.
I created an index.

I used the following "Costum Column":

```
List.Sum(List.Range(#"Added Index"[Sum],0,[Index]))
```

I get this error: "Expression.Error: The column 'Sum' of the table wasn't found."

I absolutely do not understand what is causing this.

Here are the power query steps taken below, starting from the creation of my index column:

```
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type3", "Index", 1, 1),
    #"Changed Type4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Index",{{"ItalyZ", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type4", "Sum ItalyZ ItalyY ItalyB", each [Z Italy]+[Y Italy]+[B Italy]),
    #"Changed Type5" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Sum ItalyZ ItalyY ItalyB", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type5", "Custom", each List.Sum(List.Range(#"Added Index"[Sum ItalyZ ItalyY ItalyB],0,[Index]))),
    #"Changed Type6" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom1",{{"Custom", type number}}),
    Custom = #"Changed Type6"{0}[Custom]
```

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of your steps/data or your M code? I just tried some dummy data and you code worked for me?

Comment: Yes I am adding it to the question...more broadly I have been trying to group, sum and continue columns with specific logic with power query, but I encounter incredible difficulties and I am frustrated, I feel stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you need to change:

`#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type5", "Custom", each List.Sum(List.Range(#"Added Index"[Sum ItalyZ ItalyY ItalyB],0,[Index]))),`

to:

`#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type5", "Custom", each List.Sum(List.Range(#"Changed Type5"[Sum ItalyZ ItalyY ItalyB],0,[Index]))),`

Note the edit from `#"Added Index"[Sum ItalyZ ItalyY ItalyB]` to `#"Changed Type5"[Sum ItalyZ ItalyY ItalyB]`

Comment: I tested it! It works! You are awesome! I am stupid ! I should have read properly and corrected myself!

Comment: No...you're *not* stupid. We *all* make that sort of mistake.